# How to get start position and end position of line in a string

Tags: java

I have a text with multiple lines and i have the line number as an input now i'd like to have the start position and end position of that line, here is what i already did but it's not working:

```
        private int[] getPos(int line) {
            String[] lines = textArea.getText().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            int i=0;
            int pos = 0;
            while( i < lines.length){
                if(i==line)
                    break;
                pos = pos+lines[i].length();

                i++;
            }

            int[] s = {pos,pos+lines[i].length()};
            return s;
        }
```

example of text:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

i want to use the result to highlight the line:

```
textArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startPos, endPos,highlightPainter);
```

Comment: can you give some example of your input line and output you wanted

Comment: @ashok_p i added an example of text

Comment: What do you intend to use the result for? The reason for asking is simple - `String[] lines = textArea.getText().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` removes line separators, so you results will be different for the array and text area. 
            `

Comment: @GermannArlington i added my reason in the question

Comment: why the down vote for???

Comment: Downvote was not from me

Comment: Now you described your intentions it is clear that you logic will not work as you will not be counting line separators, so your result will be off by `line.separator.length * lineNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the first instance of the substring (or are sure that there will be only one), you can use the [`.indexOf(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String foo = "foo bar";
String toLookUp = "bar";
int initialPosition = foo.indexOf(toLookUp);
System.out.println("Initial Position: " + initialPosition + " end: " + initialPosition + toLookUp.length);
```

Alternatively:

```
String foo = "foo bar bar";
String toLookUp = "bar";
int initialPosition = foo.indexOf(toLookUp);
while(initialPosition != -1)
{
     System.out.println("Initial Position: " + initialPosition + " end: " + initialPosition + toLookUp.length);
     initialPosition = foo.indexOf(toLookUp, initialPosition + toLookUp.length;
}
```

Comment: no my question is clear, i want the start position and end position that's all.

Comment: @npinti - your code does not cater for duplicate lines and it does not find position of line by line number...

Answer (score 2):

```
jText.getText().indexOf( lines[i] )
```

This will give you the start position. Add the line length to that and you have the end.

Cheers

EDIT: If there are duplicated lines, you may have to tweak the code a bit to either get the first or last line it finds.

Answer (score 1):

Because your lines counter start from '1' and your array counter start from '0' you get wrong output.

You need need to add `line -= 1;` after `int pos = 0;` and you get correct output.